# Filepond in Heroku - what is the valid path for the server attribute?

Tags: vue.js, heroku, filepond

```
<file-pond
  :allow-multiple="true"
  :accepted-file-types="['application/pdf']"
  server="/tmp"
/>
```

This works locally but when it gets deployed on Heroku, it doesn't support `/tmp` resulting in the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

I tried to look up Heroku documents on handling file uploads and it "seems" to support the `/tmp` from the root path of the current domain but it's still giving me an error.

Comment: Last time I checked, Heroku was not meant for file hosting. Look into AWS, GCP or any kind of cloud computing platform where you could store your assets.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @kissu -- I should have clarified in my original question that I am not using Heroku to host files. I am using AWS as our file hosting solution. The `server="/tmp"` attribute is used as part of the file upload process (a temporary location).

Comment: So, you're gonna host it on server A but want to upload it progressively on server B? I would do that directly on server A, that way you have less to worry and AWS is made for that anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kissu, and I'll work on changing our strategy to do it directly on Server A. Much appreciated.